# fatal error: gazebo/common/Plugin.hh: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, ros, gazebo-simu

I got this error and solved it like this.

```
cd <your catkin ws path>/src/<package>/

PKG_CONFIG_PATH=`rospack find gazebo`/gazebo/lib/pkgconfig cmake ..
```

[references](https://answers.ros.org/question/42706/gazebohh-not-found/)

hmm

I noticed that the above doesn't make the package load sadly. When I deleted workspace and reinstalled it, this error went away.